# What book is Houtarou reading in episode 2 of Hyouka?

Tags: hyouka

In episode 2 of Hyouka, Houtarou is shown reading a book throughout the episode. What book is it?

[image: Houtarou reading]

[image: Houtarou being prevented from reading]

Answer (score 2):

Houtarou is reading ***On Decadence*** (堕落論 = *Daraku-ron*, sometimes also translated *Discourse on Decadence*), by Ango SAKAGUCHI.

[image: On Decadence]

[image: photo of an actual copy of the same edition of On Decadence]

(image source: [this blog](http://blogs.yahoo.co.jp/chanchan_yanagi/52389941.html))

Sakaguchi was a novelist, essayist, and critic who lived from 1906-1955. He gained immense popularity in the immediate post-war period with his 1946 essay *On Decadence*, which criticized pre-war Japan as too heavily steeped in *bushido* culture, and argued that though post-war Japan was decadent, it was better than what came before.

*On Decadence* is not mentioned in the *Kotenbu* series of novels on which *Hyouka* is based.

In an amusing connection, the anime [*Un-Go*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Un-Go) (written アンゴ = *ango* in Japanese and hence pronounced identically to Sakaguchi's given name) was based on one of Sakaguchi's period novels - *Meiji Kaika Ango Torimono-chou*, loosely "Ango's Tales of Detectives from the Dawn of the Meiji Period".